# g++ bug when using -O2 and missing return statement?

Tags: optimization, g++

I have some C++ code that I'm compiling with the GNU C++ compiler.
Yesterday I decided to add optimization using the -O2 flag which resulted in my program segfaulting.

I've narrowed the problem down to a missing return statement that caused very weird behavior.

```
int TSelection::getXY(int X,int Y){
    int index = X + (mAreaX * (Y));
    if(index < (mAreaX * mAreaY)){
        return index;
    }
    std::cout << "OVERFLOW!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


int TSelection::calcSelectionBorder(){  

        if(mSelected.size() == 0){
            bHasSelection = false;
            return 0;
        }

        bHasSelection = true;
        
        for(int i=0; i < mAreaY; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < mAreaX; j++){
                if(isInSelection((getXY(j,i)))){
                    mSelectionBorder[(getXY(j,i))] = true;
                } else {
                    mSelectionBorder[(getXY(j,i))] = false;
                }
                mSelectionEdges[(getXY(j,i))] = 0;
            }
        }
                
        for(int yy=0; yy < mAreaY; yy++){
                    for(int xx=0; xx < mAreaX; xx++){                
                        std::cout << "X,Y: " << xx << "," << yy << " : " << mAreaY << std::endl;
                if(mSelectionBorder[getXY(xx,yy)]){                 
                    if(yy == 0){
                                mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 1;
                                } else {
                        if(!mSelectionBorder[getXY(xx,yy-1)]){
                            mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 1;
                        }
                    } 
                    if(xx == 0){
                                        mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 8;
                                } else {
                        if(!mSelectionBorder[getXY(xx-1,yy)]){
                                mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 8;
                        }                     
                    }
                    if(yy == (mAreaY-1)){
                                    mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 4;
                                } else {
                        if(!mSelectionBorder[getXY(xx,yy+1)]){
                            mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 4;
                        }                        
                    }
                    if(xx == (mAreaX-1)){                        
                                        mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 2;
                                } else {
                        if(!mSelectionBorder[getXY(xx+1,yy)]){                        
                            mSelectionEdges[getXY(xx,yy)] += 2;
                        }                        
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
    //return 0;
}
```

Without the "return 0;" and using -O2 the variable yy will just keep incrementing for ever until the program segfaults.

How can a missing return statement cause this much trouble?

My g++ version is: 11.3.0
The entire test code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/Hd1fTfT3

Comment: The missing return is a bug in your code that you need to fix. You promised in the signature that your function would return an int. Make sure you have your compiler warnings enabled too, that is diagnosable.

Comment: @Mat I understand that I have to have the return statement, I just don't understand how it being missing can cause this weird behavior?

Comment: That's just a case of undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to optimize code _assuming_ that it is correct/free of undefined behavior. If that assumption is invalid (like here), pretty much anything can happen. Different optimizer settings can lead to completely different execution behavior.

Comment: Optimizers of mainstream compilers typically *assume code paths having undefined behaviours cannot be executed*. This enable further optimizations. They can also do crazy decisions including crashing when an undefined behaviours happens. They can safely assume the end of the function is a dead code so the loop should never end. If so, the loop conditional is not even needed : it makes things slower after all for no reason! Lets remove it this useless check ;) .